# how can we enable combobox based on the value selected in another combo box in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

how can we enable combobox based on the value selected in another combo box in C# winform.

I have two combo box as shown below. Need to enable second combo box based on the value selected in first combo box. Note that the first value of combobox1 is defualt value and combobox 2 needs to be disabled but if any other value is selected the combobox 2 should be enabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ya2U.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 2 combo boxes, `combobox1` and `combobox2`

Start by adding an event listener to `combobox1`. From there, you can check whether your option has been selected

```
        comboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //
                // Get the source of the component, which is our combo
                // box.
                //
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();

                Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                if(selected.toString().equals("item1"))
                    combobox2.Enabled = True;
                else if(selected.toString().equals("item2"))
                    combobox2.Enabled = False;


            }
        });
```

Comment: i want combobox2 enabled when any value of combobox1 is selected except the first value.

Comment: set `combobox2.Enabled = False` outside the function, then under `if(selected.toString().equals("item1"))` set `combobox2.Enabled = False`